# How to limit a form submission rate per user

Tags: php, database, forms, api, throttling

I am trying to limit a `form's` submission rate to one per user per 120 seconds.

I was thinking about using a `$_SESSION` variable, but I'm not sure how that would work, and cookies can just be deleted. I guess a `$_SESSION` variable could be worked around by an intuitive user just by `logging out` and back in.

I'm just theorizing at the moment so I do not have code.

How do I get around my problem?

EDIT --

The reason the user would be querying so often is because it is an item and bestiary database. I need to slow down user queries to an acceptable rate because going over the rate of 10 queries/minute or else the application may be "banned" or denied for about an hour.

Comment: Stored their IP on submission into table w/ expiration of 1 hour. If amount of records was above 5, didn't allow submission of form.

Comment: Huh, that could work. Interesting work around. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Generally there is no solution to the problem. You need to provide more context, like is the user authenticated or not? Why does the user submit that often? And why does this constitute a problem for your application? (Like cookies, users can change their IP address easily, too)

Comment: Adding info Hakre, one minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` variables could be removed by the user, and are therefore abused by them.  You need to store the submits somewhere on your server.  Perhaps with MySQL.  Then do a check before processing the form.

Something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) attempts, MAX(submit_time) last
FROM form_submits
WHERE user_id = ?
AND submit_time > NOW - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

Then

```
if ($row['attempts'] > 0) {

    echo "You must wait " . (time() - strtotime($row['last'])) . " seconds before you can submit this form again.";
    return;
}
```