# What is best practice to prevent double form submit

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Recently I am working on a project which using ajax to call java servlet, and the request takes more than 10 sec to get the response, so I need to make sure during this time user won't be able to submit the form again, and my current approach is detect submit button click event and disable submit button, once success or error function is triggered in ajax, enable the button again, but this is not a good approach.

---- Edit ----
Sorry, I wasn't explain clearly, what I mean is this can stop non technical background user, but if any one intend to attack the site or whatever reason, 
they can simply modify html code to enable the button, and do another submit,

Before I tried another way which set a cookie interval after form submit, and check the cookie when request finish, but just wondering whether there is any other way to do this, this question is purely for learning purpose.

Sorry for my English:)

Comment: Why is disabling the submit button not a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see anything wrong with disabling the button, that is what I frequently use, because this not only provides an indication that the system acknowledged your click but also prevent the user from clicking again.

If for some reason you dont like that you can disable the underlying method call something like this:

```
var isSubmitting = false;

function handleClick(){
    if (!isSubmitting)
    {
        isSubmitting = true;
        $.ajax(
            "http://yourservice/submit" {
                data: {someData:123},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(){
                    isSubmitting = false;
                },

            });

    }
}
```

About your edit, the cookie sounds like a good approach, basically you need something that the server is going to pass to the client, and then check on submit. once that has been authorized the server will prevent processing of further requests with the same parameter.

But bear in mind that a malicious user would spawn thousands of requests to get cookies and then perform all the submissions anyway, so it is not really a defence against attackers, for that you would have to implement some form of [throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379239/how-to-limit-a-form-submission-rate-per-user).

So in the end if you just want to prevent accidental submissions the button hide will suffice.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! This approach is doing fine, but still need to deal with the scope of isSubmitting.

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by deal with the scope? You just need to place that variable in a sensible place, but if you keep the structure above then there wont be any scoping problems. I cannt tell you a good place to declare it unless you show me some of your code.

Comment: I mean for me, sometime there are thousands lines of code, I might forgot I have declared this variable somewhere, since I am not a good javascript programmer.

Comment: just do the assignment before your click handler

Comment: ok, do you think cookie would be a better way to deal with this? please see my edit part in the question

Comment: can you please also help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227083/java-response-to-ajax-with-accented-characters-garbled?noredirect=1#comment48558322_30227083

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote you up, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Something I have done and has been successful is a combination of what you described and preventing the function called by the button to execute twice. I do this by keeping a variable that gets set to true with the first request, then on subsequent request I check for it, if it's true, I don't do anything. Something like this:

```
var isRequestAlive = false;

var submit = function(){
    if(!isRequestAlive){
        isRequestAlive = true;
        doAjaxStuff("", function(){
            isRequestAlive = false;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is of course a very simplistic example a things like scoping need to be considered, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Just curious why would you do both? I mean if you disable button it also disables the function call....

Comment: Thinking of a timing issue where the second click is so fast that it happens before we (set the variable (isRequestAlive) to true) I mean, disable the button.

Comment: @jarz I agree with jarz, any deplay would allow a double click

Comment: If you disable the button on the click handler before the ajax call starts then you cannot be that fast since that process is sincronous. So no there is no delay between the click handler and another click